# Is it possible to execute nested queries with conditional promises in sequelize in a single transaction?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to perform an update to a object with several relations. One of those relations is many to many and I use `product.setCategories([categories])` to set/update them:

```
var p = req.product;
var cIds = [];

return models.sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
    var promises = [];
    //check if the product is supposed to have categories
    if (req.body.categories) {
        req.body.categories.forEach(function (c) {
            cIds.push(c.id);
        });
        promises.push(models.category.findAll({
            where: { id: { $in: cIds } },
            transaction: t
        }).then(function (categories) {
            p.setCategories(categories, { through: 'productsCategories' });
        }));
    } else if (p.categories.length > 0) {
        //delete existing categories
        promises.push(p.setCategories([], { transaction: t, through: 'productsCategories' }));
    }

    /add some more queries to "promises" and:
    return models.sequelize.Promise.all(promises);

}).then(function (result) {
    res.json(result);
}).catch(function (error) {
    respondError(res, error);
});
```

I was trying to do that in a single transaction ("t") but I can't see how since I need a nested query that is executed only after retrieving categories from database.

Can I do it in a single transaction? Is this the best way to update manyToMany?

I'm using sequelize v3.23.3 with Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

```
return models.sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
    //check if the product is supposed to have categories
    if (req.body.categories) {
        req.body.categories.forEach(function (c) {
            cIds.push(c.id);
        });
        return models.category.findAll({
            where: { id: { $in: cIds } },
            transaction: t
        }).then(function (categories) {
            p.setCategories(categories);
        });
        // OR
        return p.setCategories(cIds)
    } else if (p.categories.length > 0) {
        //delete existing categories
        return p.setCategories([], { transaction: t, through: 'productsCategories' });
    }
});
```

If you are only doing a single action at a time - here you are either setting to an array or setting to nothing, you can simply return from each branch in the if statement, no need to end with `.all`. If you are on a fairly recent version of sequelize you can also simply pass the  `cIds` directly to `setCategories`.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough but I removed several promises that are being added to promises queue for sake of simplicity, so I don't think I can't waive the '.all'. The tip that I can simply add the ids array is very nice thank you, but I still don't know if  I can execute nested queries with conditional promises in sequelize in a single transaction. Can I? Thank you

Comment: I'm not exaclty sure what you mean by conditional promises? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Imagine that I want to update an object in a single transaction, and for that  I need 5 to 10 operations depending on context. One by one I check if the query is needed (conditional) and if so I add it to promises[] and execute them all in the end. That's fine if they can run independently, but not if some of them need to be nested inside other query.